# Service repository pattern design considerations

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, design-patterns, repository-pattern

The following code is working just fine but I have a few questions realated to it's design.

BlogEntry.cs

```
    public class BlogEntry : EntityBase
    {
       /// <summary>
       /// Gets or sets the blog entry comments.
       /// </summary>
       public virtual ICollection<BlogEntryComment> BlogEntryComments { get; set; }
    }
```

BlogEntryComment.cs

```
public class BlogEntryComment : EntityBase//, IValidatableObject
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the comment.
    /// </summary>
    [StringLength(2500)]
    [Required(ErrorMessageResourceName = "Comment", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Validation))]
    [AllowHtml]
    public string Comment { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the blog entry id.
    /// </summary>
    public Guid BlogEntryId { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the blog entry.
    /// </summary>
    public virtual BlogEntry BlogEntry { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the user id.
    /// </summary>
    public Guid UserId { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the author.
    /// </summary>
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
}
```

BlogController.cs

```
    [HttpPost]
    public virtual ActionResult PostComment(Guid id, BlogEntryComment blogEntryComment)
    {
        var blogEntry = this.BlogEntryService.GetById(id);

        if (blogEntry == null)
        {
            if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
                return Json(new { success = false, message = "Blog entry not found" });

            return new HttpNotFoundWithViewResult("NotFound");
        }

        var user = UserService.GetByUsername(User.Identity.Name);

        if (user == null)
        {
            if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
                return Json(new { success = false, message = "Unknown user!" });

            return new HttpUnauthorizedResult();
        }

        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var errorModel = new BlogEntryDetail()
            {
                BlogEntry = blogEntry,
                HideNewCommentsForm = false
            };

            if (this.Request.IsAjaxRequest())
            {
                return PartialView(MVC.Blog.Views._CommentsControl, errorModel);
            }
            else
            {
                errorModel.RelatedBlogEntries = this.BlogEntryService.GetRelatedBlogEntries(false, blogEntry, 3).ToArray();
                return View(errorModel);
            }
        }

        blogEntryComment.User = user;
        blogEntryComment.BlogEntry = blogEntry;

        this.BlogEntryCommentService.Add(blogEntryComment);

        var model = new BlogEntryDetail()
        {
            BlogEntry = blogEntry,
            HideNewCommentsForm = true
        };

        if (this.Request.IsAjaxRequest())
        {
            return PartialView(MVC.Blog.Views._CommentsControl, model);
        }
        else
        {
            model.RelatedBlogEntries = this.BlogEntryService.GetRelatedBlogEntries(false, blogEntry, 3).ToArray();
            return View(model);
        }
    }
```

BlogEntryService.cs

```
public class BlogEntryService : GenericEntityService<BlogEntry>, IBlogEntryService
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="BlogEntryService"/> class.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="unitOfWork">The <see cref="IUnitOfWork"/>.</param>
    public BlogEntryService(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork)
        : base(unitOfWork.BlogEntries, unitOfWork)
    {
    }
```

GenericEntityService.cs

```
public abstract class GenericEntityService<T> : IGenericEntityService<T> where T : MVCBlog.Core.Entities.EntityBase
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="GenericEntityService&lt;T&gt;"/> class.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="repository">The <see cref="MVCBlog.Core.Repository.IRepository{T}"/>.</param>
    /// <param name="unitOfWork">The <see cref="IUnitOfWork"/>.</param>
    protected GenericEntityService(IRepository<T> repository, IUnitOfWork unitOfWork)
    {
        this.Repository = repository;
        this.UnitOfWork = unitOfWork;
    }
```

}

- The comment should be added to the database with a method of BlogEntryService.AddComment(..) or with it's own BlogEntryCommentService.Add(..) as with current implementation?
- I'm validating User and BlogEntry in the controller, this validation should be part of the service layer? for example [Service].AddComment(Guid blogEntryId, string username, string comment)
- Any other idea to improve the desing or code?

Comment: And where are your repository?

Comment: Updated the code with my Service/Repository/UnitofWork

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Acording to SRP (Single Response Principal) it should be BlogEntryCommentService.Add(..).
2. I suppose, this is not servicelayer validation.